# Displaying toast before app closes in java

Tags: java, android, timer, toast

I have created a simple dice game in Android. When the user hits an "end game" button, I want to display a toast that says "thanks for playing" and then close the application. Currently, this is what I am doing (note that I have a global timer declared as `Timer timer;`).

```
if (v.equals(endGame)) { //if "end game" button was clicked
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks for playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();
    }, 2000, 2000);

    System.exit(0); //quits the app
```

Currently, the application simply quits without the toast displaying. What do I need to do to properly implement this?

Comment: have you tried a handler instead of timer?

Comment: No, I have not. How would that work??

Comment: basically call your toast on the main thread, then add a handler that 2 seconds later quits the app... many examples of handlers can be found here on stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (I might have a bracket off)

```
if (v.equals(endGame)) { //if "end game" button was clicked
Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks for playing",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.show();
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // end app;
            }
        }, 2000);   //2 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just override the `onBackPressed()` method to check whenever the user presses the Back button to exit from your main activity. In that method, just pop up your toast and then terminate the program.

If it is that another button functionality is provided for Exit, call the `onBackPressed()` method from you `Button.onClick` and that should call your overridden method just fine.